# How can I make a TextInput recognize a dictionary on kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, kivy

My App needs to recognize the user in the first screen to go to the second screen. How can a make a button that only works if the textinput is in a dictionary?
This Button should be on the screen: 'User'

## this is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
import time
import random


'''
A DICTIONARY AS AN EXAMPLE
'''
dic = {}
dic['a'] = 2


class Mapa(Screen):
    pass

class Calendario(Screen):
    pass

class Professores(Screen):
    pass

class Sair(Screen):
    pass

class Usuario(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''

#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

MyScreenManager:

    transition: FadeTransition()
    User:
    Calendario:
    Mapa:
    Professores:
    Sair:

<User>:
    a: _a
    name: 'User'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'User'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_y: 1.7
            size_hint_x: .95
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            size_hint_x: .6
            height: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y':.6}
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Login"
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id: _a
                font_size: 30
                multline: False
        Button:
            text: 'go'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint_y: .1
            size_hint_x: .1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y':.4}
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'
            #if _a in dic:
                #on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'




<Calendario>:
    name: 'Calendario'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Calendario'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: [1,.2]

        BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Mapa'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Mapa'
            Button:
                text: 'Calendario'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'

            Button:
                text: 'Professores'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Professores'

            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Usuario'

<Mapa>:
    name: 'Mapa'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Mapa'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: [1,.2]

        BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Mapa'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Mapa'
            Button:
                text: 'Calendario'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'

            Button:
                text: 'Professores'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Professores'

            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Usuario'

<Professores>:
    name: 'Professores'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Professores'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: [1,.2]

        BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Mapa'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Mapa'
            Button:
                text: 'Calendario'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'

            Button:
                text: 'Professores'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Professores'

            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Usuario'

<Sair>:
    name: 'Sair'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Sair'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: [1,.2]

        BoxLayout:

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Mapa'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Mapa'
            Button:
                text: 'Calendario'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Calendario'

            Button:
                text: 'Professores'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Professores'

            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: [1,.2]
                on_release: app.root.current = 'Usuario'

''')

class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget
ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#: import dic main.dic
```

where main is the name of your .py file

then in the body of your kv file you should be able to do:

```
on_release: if dic['a']==2: app.root.current = 'Calendario'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's that one(and ugly) way how to do that as howMuchCheeseIsTooMuchCheese answered. Ugly it's because of the way you defined your dict(as a global), so there's no pretty way how to play with that.

Kivy on the other side has a main class - [`App`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html), which is used in every application if you don't go the hard way with `runTouchApp()` directly, so the best for you would be to get that

```
dic = {}
dic['a'] = 2
```

from your global space and put it where it belongs, or use a better global way i.e. [`get_running_app`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) and put these lines inside an `App` class either in `__init__` or as a class variable.

Then the easiest way to access it it with `app.<variable>` in kv + you can play nicely with other classes if you connect them with `get_running_app()` together and make `App` class handle the communication.